# How to add a second site in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, centos7, httpd.conf

I'm using the following configuration of httpd.conf in my CentOs 7 Apache server to run "site1":

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName locahost:80
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site1"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html/site1">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

When I access "http://localhost", site1 and its subpages/subfolders work correctly.
I want now to be able to display a second website: when accessing "http://localhost/site2", I want to display the content of a file "test.html" saved under "/test"; how should I edit the httpd.conf to make it work?

Comment: Any hints? I made several attempts, but I'm stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not a different site, it is a different directory. A different site would involve a different hostname.

Since you already have `DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site1` and you don't seem to want to create a new virtualhost you can point to a new/different directory with `Alias`

Also you just want site2 to load test.html under /test/ If I understood correctly when visited, just add the proper `DirectoryIndex` directive to it.

Here it is:

```
Alias /site2 /var/www/html/site2
<Directory /var/www/html/site2>
     DirectoryIndex /test/test.html
</Directory>
```

For this to work you need these two modules:

- mod_alias
- mod_dir (but you may already have this one as you are already using DirectoryIndex directive)

You could also mkdir site2 under site1 but, this may look cleaner.